# AngularJS get $pristine state of an individual field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form in Angular which contains rows of fields, where each row is an `ng-repeat` block:

```
<form name="myForm><table>
<tr class="item-row" ng-repeat="item in items">
  <td>
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.width" ng-change="processItem(item)">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.relatedWidth" ng-change="processItem(item)">
  </td>
</tr>
</table></form>
```

In my `$scope.processItem(item)` method I want the `item.relatedWidth` to match the value of `item.width` *only if* the field for `item.relatedWidth` is pristine - i.e. it's not been edited by the user. If the user edits the field then it should be decoupled.

In *pseudocode* I want to do this:

```
$scope.processItem = function(item){
  if(the field for item.relatedWidth is pristine){
    item.relatedWidth = item.width;
  }
}
```

I can see that the field has the class `ng-pristine` or `ng-dirty` but I don't know how to fetch this value the Angular way.

How can I read this $pristine / $dirty state of the field given that it is dynamically rendered in a row by `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `ng-form` directive to each row, add `name` attribute to inputs and pass pristine status of relatedWidth input to the `processItem` function:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <table>
    <tr class="item-row" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-form="itemForm">
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="width" ng-model="item.width" 
            ng-change="processItem(item, itemForm.related_width.$pristine)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="related_width" ng-model="item.relatedWidth" 
            ng-change="processItem(item)">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.processItem = function(item, relatedPristine){
  if(relatedPristine === true){
    item.relatedWidth = item.width;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your fields in a fieldset,

```
<form name="testForm">
    <fieldset>
        <input name="testField" type="text" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Now you can access your form like this,

$scope.testForm

```
for(var field in $scope.testForm)
{
    if($scope.testForm[field].$pristine)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Now no matter how many fields are added using ng-repeat inside the fieldset, it will still be in $scope.testForm and will be accessible.

Comment: The accepted answer worked for me, although this was also very helpful. Wrapping fields in a `<fieldset>` with a name it's possible to check `$pristine` on a collection of related fields (which is needed in my real-world not-so-simple scenario)